# Cannot access object properties (weird as it should work as it always does)

Tags: javascript, object

I have a really weird problem. I'm trying to access a subobject but it just won't work. The easiest way is to just show you the console output of FireBug:

```
console.log(DesignDocument)

DesignDocument: mwrNsBrowser
    html: e.fn.e.init[1]
    name: "Game Design Document"
    rootName: "Game Design Document"
    __proto__: Object
        afterLoadCategory: function (bitData, catName)...
        bits: Object
        hide: function ()...
        html: ""
        loadCategory: function (catName, parentBit)...
        name: ""
        rootName: ""
        show: function ()...
        tmp: Object
```

Now I'm trying to access the "bits" object defined in prototype. Works fine, too.

```
console.log(DesignDocument.bits)

Object
    DocumentSet1: Array[1]
        0: mwrBrowserBit
        length: 1
```

But here's the problem. I try to get the "DocumentSet1" Array:

```
var selector = "DocumentSet1";
console.log(DesignDocument.bits[selector])

undefined
```

And it just returns "undefined"!
I'm currently out of ideas about why this won't work. Hope someone can just tell me I was too dumb...

Comment: That is strange. What does `for(var x in DesignDocument.bits) console.log(x);` output?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. As if there was nothing in it!

Comment: I almost think I found the problem. FireBug doesn't really "dump" the object but shows it in the current state. So I can only see how the object looks in the moment I check it in the console, but not in the moment javascript tries to access the certain bit.
And as there's some AJAX and asynchronous stuff involved, it seems like the bit isn't defined in that moment.
Will tell you if it works after fixin this...

Comment: ok its fixed! For everyone running into the same problem, there's a smart function which allows you to view the object as it looks to that moment and not "now". Check out http://refactormycode.com/codes/226-recursively-dump-an-object

Comment: You should add that as answer to this question (and then accept that answer) so that this question doesn't linger forever in the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0):

The array DocumentSet1 is a property of the DesignDocument.bits object so the right syntax for logging it to the console would be:

```
console.log(DesignDocument.bits.DocumentSet1);
```

or if you want to show a specific item in the array:

```
console.log(DesignDocument.bits.DocumentSet1[num]);
```